# Sinalização rejeitada após edição da questão

Tags: suporte

Hoje eu me deparei com [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82394/erro-em-update-mysql) que (como podem ver no histórico e no meu comentário) estava em Inglês, então eu sinalizei-a como **fora de escopo** com a opção de que não estava em português e fiz um comentário dizendo para o usuário que aqui só eram aceitas questões em português.

Como o usuário editou logo a questão, minha sinalização foi marcada como **rejeitada**.

Eu só gostaria de saber se isso está correto, pois eu sinalizei a questão antes do usuário edita-lá.

Comment: Estou tentando entender o que aconteceu pois foi rejeitado pelo próprio sistema, não foi algum moderador que a rejeitou.

Comment: Aparentemente a edição da pergunta não marca sua sinalização como "útil", por si só. Daí então sua sinalização foi para a [fila de análises](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/39888) e lá ela foi rejeitada pois quando os usuários a analisaram ela já estava traduzida. Por ter sido editada, o sistema poderia ao menos ter marcado como "disputado", pois não dava para ter certeza de como era a questão no momento em que você sinalizou.

Comment: @Math Não foi a sinalização que levou pra análise, foi o voto anterior de outro usuário. O sistema é injusto mesmo, porque esse usuário não teve nada rejeitado (porque ele não sinalizou, tem privilégio de votar pra fechar).

Comment: @Math não tem como mudar isso? Agora se eu tentar sinalizar algo fica me aparecendo um aviso para tomar cuidado *porque uma sinalização minha foi rejeitada*. Não que isso seja um grande problema, mas é chato.

Comment: Para parar de receber os avisos basta fazer sinalizações que sejam marcadas como úteis. Sei que não é o ideal pois fica aquele sentimento de injustiça no caso em questão, mas infelizmente não é possível mudar o resultado dessa sinalização.